# Disappeared photos

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery

I have Copied my photos from Lumix camera to laptop with Windows 7 and now I can only see half of the amount of photos on my camera.

The amount of MB tells me that the ones I cannot see are also there on the camera.

Can anybody tell me what has happened and how I can make these photos to be seen again on camera, please?

Comment: The whole point of copying the files to a computer/laptop is to make room for new content on the camera.  You can use PhotoRec to try and get them back.

Comment: Is this tagged as linux because it looks similar to Lumix?